# Assets gem throws file not found error in assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have created an assets gem out of jquery simple faq.
https://github.com/MavenHive/jquery_simplefaq

I have added below line to my application.js file.

```
//= require simplefaq
```

When I run assets:precompile on my local I get below error.

```
rake aborted!
couldn't find file 'simplefaq'
```

To investigate the problem I cloned the gem to my local machine and referred to it using path.

```
gem 'jquery_simplefaq', :path => '/path/to/jquery_simplefaq'
```

This works perfectly well. Changing this to use the git url for local gem repository throws the file not found error.

```
gem 'jquery_simplefaq', :git => 'file:///path/to/jquery_simplefaq'
```

Using :path works and :git throws error. What am I missing?

Update:

The error message

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/bin/ruby /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf@gemset2/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
couldn't find file 'simplefaq'
  (in /home/user/code-repo/proj/webapp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:27)
```

You can replicate this error by adding the gem to any rails 3 app.

```
gem 'jquery_simplefaq', :git => 'git://github.com/MavenHive/jquery_simplefaq'
```

Add below line to your application.js.

```
//= require simplefaq
```

Run assets:precompile

Comment: did you run `bundle install` after changing your gemfile

Comment: Yes, I ran bundle install. I also verified that the gem is installed in my rvm gemset.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: I have updated the question with the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I forked your repository and got this working. You have a little mixup in your gemspec-file.

Currently, you have this:

```
# jquery_simplefaq.gemspec
spec.files = `git ls-files`.split($/)
# ...
spec.require_paths = Dir["{lib,vendor}/**/*"] + ["README.md"]
```

Change it to something like this:

```
spec.files = Dir["{lib,vendor}/**/*"] + ["README.md"]
# ...
spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

After that, precompiling should work

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works well. Just little curious why this error was not being thrown when I used :path to refer to the local gem.

Comment: just run the `git ls-files` command directly in your console and you'll see that the required files are missing